# relationship between share size and entropy in secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing, information-theory

In an $(s,r,n)$-ramp scheme, we require that any
subset of at least $r$ parties can recover the secret, while any subset of size at most $s$ cannot learn anything about the secret.
In Bogdanov et al.'s [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a3f6/49bc2f1a22fa0b2bf67bec916d52337dcee0.pdf), they prove that any $(s,r,n)$-ramp secret sharing scheme for a one-bit secret requires shares of at least $\log((r+1)/(r-s))$ bits.

**My question.** Does share size (e.g. $\log((r+1)/(r-s))$ bits) have anything to do with the *entropy* of information which each party holds? A naive approach (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281290/)) shows that the *sum* of entropy of information assigned to each party should be greater than $\frac{n}{r-s}$ bits, when sharing a one-bit secret. Is this bound tight?